# Catch event of backdrop click on AngularJS modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I create a modal window

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: app.controller,
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                scope: function () {
                    return $scope;
                }
            }
        });

modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
            alert("Success");
        }, function () {
        });
```

But when I click over the opened modal window, it closes. I want to catch event, when user clicked over the modal window. My modal controller:

```
app.controller = function(){}
```

and modal view:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              Hello
 </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for ng mouse events, I think it is what your looking for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseup.